# nested ES6 Template Literals not returning any values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to execute some javascript code as a string using eval. The issue i'm having is that the string(which is a template literal) has nested template literals e.g. ${obj.height}. that are failing to execute.

How do i get this to execute and make template literals return their values?

```
let code = `
  let obj = {
  height: 150,
  width: 30,
  top: 10,
  left: 30,
  position: "absolute"
  }

 $(pageContainer).append(
   <iframe type="text/html"
       style="height:${obj.height}; width:${obj.width};top:${obj.top}; left:${obj.left}; position:${obj.position};"
       src="dummy url"
       frameborder="0">
           </iframe>
 );

 `;

 eval(code);
```

Comment: *I'm trying to execute some javascript code as a string using eval.* And that's the first mistake...

Comment: Youre missing the `

Comment: What kind of syntax is `$(pagecontainer).append(<iframe...`?

Comment: This won't work at all. `obj` will be taken from the surrounding context at the time the template string is defined, not from some internally defined variable at the time of `eval`. Try putting the `style` attribute value in another template string.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want something like this:

```js
const code=`let x = {foo: 42}; console.log(${`x.foo`})`;

eval(code);
```

Comment: What's the difference between that and const code=\`let x = {foo: 42}; console.log(x.foo)\`; ?

Comment: Nothing, but in theory, he could interpolate something into the string to be `eval`'ed.